# Creating a virtual file on disk

Tags: c#, file, process, stream, filesystems

I have an external program (as an executable binary) that consumes input files that potentially could be very large. I'm writing a C# application that will take data from our DB; write a segment of it to a temp directory; then invoke the external program (via Process.Run()) to consume the temp files and produce some output.

The external program does not allow input redirection (i.e. "program < file.txt"); it can only open files in the filesystem. However, I've noticed that some of these input files are kind of a waste of space: in my special case, they basically amount to the same line repeated over and over.

Is there something I can do to dynamically generate these files/streams on demand, without actually writing them out to disk ? I looked at memory mapped files, but I don't think I can force the target executable to consume them...

Comment: Is that a 3rd party tool?

Comment: one non-file creating route might be: Write the file's bytes to a table in a database then send a pointer reference to the consumer. The consumer can be responsible for garbage clean up or maybe have a date stamp and clean up after a set amount of time.

Comment: Yes, it is a third-party tool; I do have its source code (in addition to the binary), but it's tens of thousands of lines of C++ which I don't have time to edit...

Comment: Is this running on Linux or Windows? Maybe a [Named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) could help?

Comment: I'm not sure about named pipes -- can I open a named pipe as though it were a file (e.g. "third_party_program --input /tmp/named_pipe"), without using IO redirection (e.g. "third_party_program < named_pipe") ?

Comment: On Linux you can just pass it as stdin and use the file name `/dev/stdin`. If you send it to a named pipe instead, called `/home/my/pipe`, then you run your program vai `third_party_program /home/my/pipe`, and it will open that pipe for read just like it would a regular file.

Answer (score 2):

Is the file's location fixed, or do you specify it as a parameter? If you can specify the path, then one thing you can do is take [CBFS Connect](https://callback.com/cbfsconnect/) (note, I am related to it) and use its Memory Drive sample (included in it) to create a virtual disk, the contents of which are stored in memory. Then, let the application in question create and use files on that virtual disk. You can either store the data in memory as is, or modify the sample to fake the data when the file is read so that memory space is not occupied by file data. The trial version would suffice if you need a virtual disk for short-term use, or maybe the sales guys will offer you a license for personal use.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting idea, and I'll check it out. Out of curiosity, will CBFS work on Linux under Mono ?

Comment: CBFS Connect includes a cross-platform FUSE component which uses the native FUSE driver on Linux and CBFS on Windows . That FUSE component has FUSE-like API for easy portability of applications, and it has .NET edition. There's a FUSE Drive sample included which is also an in-memory disk.

Comment: Great, thank you -- I've sent an email to the CBFS sales team with some followup questions.